# Maximum minimal degree $\delta(G)$ for connected, non-Hamiltonian $G$

Tags: graph-theory

For a finite, simple undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ let $\delta(G)$ denote the minimum degree of all vertices. For any integer $k\geq 4$ let $N(k)$ denote the maximum $\delta(G)$ that a connected graph $G$ on $k$ vertices can have such that $G$ does **not** have a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).

Do we have $\lim \sup_{k\to \infty} \frac{N(k)}{k} = 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a graph with $\delta(G)\geqslant (k-1)/2$ has Hamiltonian path by Dirac's theorem. But for $\delta(G)=(k-2)/2$ this is already not always so, see $K_{m,m+2}$.

Comment: A minor nitpick, but $K_{m,m+1}$ does have a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: Ah, path. I thought about cycle.